# Unable to kill rosnode running in background

Tags: rosnode

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I killed `my_node` using

> rosnode kill my_node

When printing a list of nodes

> rosnode list

`my_node` is not showing up the nodes, but it is running in the background and I confirmed it using the following command:

> ps aux | grep my_node | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}'

This shows a list of `my_node`, because I started the `my_node` many times.

> kill $(ps aux | grep my_node | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}')

Is not killing any of the nodes

I have tried, `pkill` as well without any luck. Only way to get out of this issue is to restart `roscore`

I would like to know if there is any other way to kill the node?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/211761/unable-to-kill-rosnode-running-in-background/) by [tosandip](https://answers.ros.org/users/22300/tosandip/) on ROS Answers with karma: 35 on 2015-06-19

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's quite likely that your node is stuck in an infinite loop somewhere or is never initializing ROS.

Usually, `kill` sends `SIGINT`, which can be caught by the process so that it can terminate gracefully. It sounds like your process is stuck somehow, and this signal is caught and ignored.

You can also tell `kill` to send the `SIGKILL` signal, which cannot be caught and causes your program to terminate immediately. You can tell `kill` to send the `SIGKILL` by name: `kill -KILL` or by number `kill -9`

Once you've cleared out any runaway processes, you should go through your code and try to understand why it's getting stuck; otherwise they'll just keep running away from you.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2015-06-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tosandip](https://answers.ros.org/users/22300/tosandip/) on 2015-06-22**:
Thanks that helped.